# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file after installing MySQL 5.6 with Homebrew on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, pid

I am getting the following error when trying to start MySQL 5.6 for the first time after installing it with Homebrew on MacOS Mojave.

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

I have read the other comments and answers on here and they suggest either setting the ownership of the /mysql dir to the current user (crmpicco) or mysql, but neither of those solutions work for me.

```
$ ll /usr/local/var/mysql/
total 221264
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql        56 21 Aug 22:09 auto.cnf
-rw----rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1680 21 Aug 22:09 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1112 21 Aug 22:09 ca.pem
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1112 21 Aug 22:09 client-cert.pem
-rw----rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1676 21 Aug 22:09 client-key.pem
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql       217 21 Aug 22:17 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql  50331648 21 Aug 22:17 ib_logfile0
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql  50331648 21 Aug 22:09 ib_logfile1
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql  12582912 21 Aug 22:17 ibdata1
-rw----rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1676 21 Aug 22:09 private_key.pem
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql       452 21 Aug 22:09 public_key.pem
-rw-r--rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1112 21 Aug 22:09 server-cert.pem
-rw----rwx  1 crmpicco  _mysql      1680 21 Aug 22:09 server-key.pem
CraigRMsMacBook:mysql crmpicco$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/CraigRMsMacBook.pid).
```

Am I missing something in my configuration?

```
$ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
CraigRMsMacBook:mysql crmpicco$ cat /etc/my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with 
# ticks/quotes escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing 
# the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
#socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions 
# are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
#socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#nice       = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

#
# * IMPORTANT
#   If you make changesi to these settings and your system uses 
#   apparmor, you may also need to also adjust 
#   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
#

#user       = mysql
#socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
#basedir    = /usr
#datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
#tmpdir     = /tmp
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
#key_buffer          = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
#myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections       = 100
#table_cache           = 64
#thread_concurrency    = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size    = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or 
# for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see 
#       README.Debian about other settings you may need 
#       to change.
#server-id          = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

# Query Caching
query-cache-type = 1

# Default to InnoDB
default-storage-engine=innodb

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

Comment: Show your config file, please. Also, locate `.err` file and show it as well. It should be named `CraigRMsMacBook.err`

Comment: @Styx Thanks for the comment. I don't have an `.err` file anywhere on my entire disk. I have updated my question with my `/etc/my.cnf`. Would it still use the `/etc/my.cnf` config even if I installed MySQL with Homebrew?

Comment: @crmpicco No. Brew-installed mysql uses conf `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`.